# 3 memory leaks in a program reading lines, even with exit() used

Tags: c, memory-management, free, valgrind

After running the program in `valgrind -v` it shows me that there are 3 unfreed blocks of memory (50 allocs, 47 frees). I'm probably failing to free `infile` `outfile` and `temp` - I guess. But when I put:

```
else {
        free(line);
            fclose(infile);  /* added lines */
            fclose(outfile); /* added lines */
            free(temp);      /* added lines */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

it doesn't compile, showing me errors about undefined use of `temp` and `outfile`.

**EDIT:**
I changed it to (in `lineRead`):

```
else {
        free(line);
            fclose(infile);
            return NULL;
}
```

and added following error catcher after `while` in `main`:

```
if ((check = readline(infile)) == NULL) {
    fclose(outfile);
}
```

However, this gives me even more errors. **Why is that?**

**/EDIT**

---

How to fix that? I though that `exit()` does all the cleaning needed...

The code is changed in [1] because I wanted to simulate that particular error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
char* lineRead(FILE* infile)
{
    char* line = NULL;
    char* newbuf = NULL;
    int c;
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    while((c=fgetc(infile)) != EOF) {
        if (size >= bufsize) {
        if (bufsize == 0)
                bufsize = 2;
        else if (bufsize <= ((size_t)-1)/2)
                bufsize = size+1;
        else {
                free(line);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        newbuf = realloc(line,bufsize);
        if (!newbuf) {
                free(line);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
        line = newbuf;
            }
        }
        if (c != '\n') {
            line[size++]=c;
        }

    }

    if(size >= bufsize) {
        if (size > (size_t)-1)      /* [1] I know that there should be*/
                            /* '<', but it is '>' just for testing errors */
        bufsize = size + 1;
        else {
        free(line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        newbuf = realloc(line,bufsize);
        if (!newbuf) {
        free(line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        line = newbuf;
    }
    line[size++]='\0';
    return line;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

 char *line=NULL; 
 char **lines=NULL; 
 int linenumber=0;
 int c;
 void *temp=NULL;

while((line=lineRead(infile))!=NULL) {
    linenumber++;
    temp=realloc(lines, (linenumber)*sizeof(char*));
    if(temp==NULL) {
    printf("Bad alloc error\n");
    free(lines);
    return 0;
    } else {
    lines=temp;
    }

}
/* processing lines */
free(lines);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two things:
1) calling `exit` is independent of Valgrind showing that you have freed memory. Exiting will clean up the memory from the OS's perspective, but it will still be shown as leaked by Valgrind because Valgrind only cares about in-process memory leaks.
2) It's pretty abusive to be constantly `realloc`ing for every byte. Every `realloc` may copy everything in that buffer. The usual strategy is to have a big buffer that you write into. If it's full, `realloc` it to be twice as large.

Comment: @apmasell Thank You for your comment, but it doesn't help me with problem. Can You please see my edit? Regarding valgrind - I need to have no errors there, I know that OS cares about clearing all the "mess" after errors, but I need to prepare code giving no errors in diagnostic tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't free

```
newbuf // in read line
line // in main
temp // Which gets free'd only on after bad malloc
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where you added free()s went, but If it is in lineread, then those other variables aren't visible there (they were declared local to main; you've defined a DIFFERENT line here).  So you'll need to either pass them as parameters or make them global.